# Python разница между датами и временем

Tags: python, datetime, время

Пишу код, который определяет разницу между временем. Между двумя объектами времени не должно быть меньше 30 минут.

```
tdelta1= datetime.timedelta(hours=time_object.hour, minutes=time_object.minute)
tdelta2 = datetime.timedelta(hours=i.backup_time.hour, minutes=i.backup_time.minute)
res=tdelta1-tdelta2
res_to_min = res.total_seconds() / 60
if res_to_min <30:
    #do something
else:
    #do something else
```

Всё это работает, кроме одного момента, когда первое время - это 23:59 текущего дня, а второе время - это 00:00 следующего дня. В этом случае попадает, что больше 30 минут. Как это исправить?

Comment: В конструкторе еще дату задавайте и всё

Comment: какое время здесь начало, а какое - конец? И откуда известно, что дни разные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime.timedelta` - это разница по времени, например, 1 час 2 минуты. Если же вам нужно чтобы

> Между двумя объектами времени не должно быть меньше 30 минут.

то здесь лучше подойдёт [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects), который представляет дату и время, т. е. какой-то момент времени. С ним ваш код будет таким:

```py
import datetime

d1 = datetime.datetime(year=1, month=1, day=2, hour=0, minute=0)  # (1)
d2 = datetime.datetime(year=1, month=1, day=1, hour=23, minute=59)  # (2)
res = d1 - d2
res_to_min = res.total_seconds() / 60  # дальше всё так же, как и было
if res_to_min <30:
    #do something
else:
    #do something else
```

Пояснения:

1. аргументы `year` и `month` - обязательные
2. вычитать нужно, конечно же, из большего меньшее

Comment: Да, Вы правы, без указания даты не обойтись. Благодарю!